# Ignore properties for nested fields of spring BeanUtils is not working

Tags: spring-bean

**How to define ignore properties for nested properties to spring BeanUtils?**

```
BeanUtils.copyProperties(source, target, ignorePropertiesName);
```

I have class Contact with nested class Name and their two propeties 'firstName' and 'lastname'.

I tried three different patterns to pass the nested filed name to ignore list, but none of them worked.

```
"contact.name.lastName"
"name.lastName"
"lastName"
```

Below is the complete unit test with class definition, I am using spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE version with java 8.

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils;

public class NestedCopyPropertiesTest {

// @Test
public void CopyProperties() {
    String firstName = "Andy";
    String lastName = "Murray";
    Contact source = new Contact(new Name(firstName, lastName));
    Contact target = new Contact(new Name(null, null));

    BeanUtils.copyProperties(source, target);

    String targetFirstName = target.getName().getFirstName();
    String targetLastName = target.getName().getLastName();
    log("targetFirstName: " + targetFirstName);
    log("targetLastName: " + targetLastName);

    Assert.assertTrue("Failed to copy nested properties.", firstName.equals(targetFirstName));
    Assert.assertTrue("Failed to copy nested properties.", lastName.equals(targetLastName));
}

@Test
public void CopyPropertiesWithIgnoreProperties() {
    String firstName = "Andy";
    String lastName = "Murray";
    Contact source = new Contact(new Name(firstName, lastName));
    Contact target = new Contact(new Name(null, null));

    // -------------NOT WORKING?
    // BeanUtils.copyProperties(source, target, "contact.name.lastName");
    // -------------NOT WORKING?
    // BeanUtils.copyProperties(source, target, "name.lastName");
    // -------------NOT WORKING?
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(source, target, "lastName");

    String targetFirstName = target.getName().getFirstName();
    String targetLastName = target.getName().getLastName();
    log("targetFirstName: " + targetFirstName);
    log("targetLastName: " + targetLastName);

    Assert.assertTrue("Failed to copy nested properties.", firstName.equals(targetFirstName));
    Assert.assertTrue("Failed to copy nested properties with ignore property.", !lastName.equals(targetLastName));
}

public void log(String string) {
    System.out.println(string);
}

public class Contact {
    private Name name;

    public Contact(Name name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Name getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(Name name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class Name {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Name(String firstName, String lastName) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

}

I looked into the java documentation, it's so generic that it doesn't give any clue how to work with nested fields. I wonder the API writer consider adding example when they create it otherwise everyone just wonder how to use it! sad